# Error CS1003 Syntax Error ',' expected (Unity C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i use unity and trying to use Rigidbody scripts and popped up with 5 errors with CS1003.

Heres my code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour 

void Start ()
 
   rb.useGravity false;

    
{ public Rigidbody rb;
   
    void Update() {
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, 1000*Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

I tried putting brackets in certain places but couldnt figure out what to put.

Answer (score 1):

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb.useGravity = false;
    }

    void Update() 
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, 1000 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

I think you want it to look a little like the above.

You are correct that your bracket closure is one of the things stopping Unity from being able to compile your program.

It seems that you are not very familiar with C# syntax in general. I would suggest reading up on these basics, it will greatly help you in developing in Unity.

Comment: Yeah I am a starter in C# so I may not know the basic syntax rules.
Sorry about that!

Comment: @Scoobis please don't apologise at all, everyone is a new starter at some point! Please take the comments as the helpful advice as which they were intended - truly if you go away and improve in this area it will help your development and overall learning so much.